# How to pre-populate a text-type input field in html via erb/ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I'm trying to get the following line to work in my Ruby on Rails project's erb.html file:

```
Student City:<input type="text" name="student[city]" value = <%= @student.city %>>
```

(This whole thing is inside of a form tag)
Everything works fine unless I give value a multi-word value, then it'll cut off everything after the space in the string.

To be specific, if student.city == "San Francisco", my page loads a text field with "San". I've tried changing it to different data types and manipulating the string and it still does the same thing. (Interestingly, trying to print the result after splitting the string into an array will display

> ["San",

Is this a known bug? Any ideas for a work around? If this is an actual bug with erb, how do I submit a bug report?

Comment: You should maintain standardized attributes and wrap everything in quotes or double-quotes, `<input type="text" name="student[city]" value="<%= @student.city %>">` — there's other things to make note of, but assuming that no city name has a double quote inside of it (it may have a single quote/apostrophe) you can just wrap it in double quotes.

Answer (score 3):

I wonder why you don't use Ruby on Rails' form helpers?

Something like:

```
<%= form_for @student do |f| %>
  Student city: <%= f.text_field :city %>
  # ...
<% end %>
```

Read more about [form helpers in the Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#binding-a-form-to-an-object).

Comment: I'll have to look into those

Answer (score 1):

You need to enclose them with **double quotes**:

```
Student City:<input type="text" name="student[city]" value="<%= @student.city %>" >
```